# How to obtain a specific field in a Firebase document

Tags: firebase, flutter

Trying to capture a specific field from my documents. Here is the code for the wrapper,

```dart
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user);

    // return either the Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return FirmHomePage();
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the code that we used for printing in the console.

```dart
void idss() async {
  FirebaseUser userid = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

  var document = await Firestore.instance.collection('Users').getDocuments();
  for (var document in document.documents) {
    messagetext = document.data['JobType'];
    usettype = messagetext;
    print(messagetext);
  }
}
```

We want to check our user to set a path for them.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseUser userid = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('Users')
.where('uid', isEqualTo: currentUser.uid) .getDocuments();

 final List < DocumentSnapshot > documents = result.documents;

 if (documents.length == 1) {
//your code here
}else{
//your code here
}
```

Comment: You can use QuerySnapshot to achieve it.....Hope it helped!!!!